# Options for closing UI app from windows service in C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, windows-services, system-tray

I'd like to hear any options for closing Win UI application from windows service.
My service runs under System account. UI application runs for every logged-in user, so there can be many app instances. I need to close them all. I know UI process name and can bind to each process instance and *kill* it. BUT UI application has tray icon which stays visible (ghost icon, disappears when hovered by mouse) after the process is killed. I'd like to close the UI application correctly, via managed or unmanaged code. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

ADDITION 1:
The UI application has no main window, but only tray icon (NotifyIcon component).

ADDITION 2:
I can modify source code of the UI application. But it is written in a way that prevents it from recieving CUSTOM window messages, only standard ones.

ADDITION 3:
The UI application does not show up any Form, it just creates ApplicationContext and executes NotifyIcon within the context.

```
Program.cs

public static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new TrayApplicationContext();
        Application.Run(context);
    }
}
```

TIA
Ivan

Comment: Do you have access to the source code of the application you are about to shutdown?

Comment: If @yas4891 is right, I gonna delete my answer...

Comment: @ivan: take a look at my edited post. You could, IMO, creating a form and run it and inside the form creating tray icon and listening to custom messages. This form musn't be visible, so I think you can achieve your goal easily...

Comment: thanks everyone for the ideas. after playing with them i had to resort to another solution - implement WCF communication between the service and the UI app instances and, from the service, notify the instances when they have to close itself. i think the most suitable idea was provided by yas4891, it works in windows 2003, but i had problems with windows 7 and had no enough patience to debug and get it working...

Answer (score 1):

Call [Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) instead of Kill.

If you have access to the source code of the WinUI app then in your main form (the one you start in `Application.Run(mainFormGoesHere)`) subscribe to the close event and make the `notifyIcon.Visible = false;` just before you exit. It is a known issue with the NotifyIcon and the system tray.

If it is a 3rd party app, then hope that they too have something implemented like this to properly clean up after being asked to close through `CloseMainWindow()`

Another approach would be to attempt to refresh the system tray from your service as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/33fdc9f0-dd55-43de-a240-8019ba1155aa/)

```
public const int WM_PAINT = 0xF;
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int character, IntPtr lpsText);


//Send WM_PAINT Message to paint System Tray which will refresh it.
SendMessage(traynotifywnd,WM_PAINT,0,IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: I think that the OP is refering to a notifyIcon that belongs to the process, he is trying to kill. I guess it is 3rd party and he does not have access to the source

Comment: tried Process.CloseMainWindow, it did not trigger the UI app closing, probably because the app has no main window (question is updated).

Comment: @ivan: Is it a Windows Form application?

Comment: @Peter Kelly: thanks for the "refresh systray" idea, but it does not help, even if refreshing is executed in context of a user UI app belongs to (i.e. not in System context).

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a WM_CLOSE message to the application:

```
const uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

[DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="SendMessage", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, int
lParam);

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

`hWnd` is the window handle of the process' main window you are trying to shut down. You possibly also need to send the same message to the window handle of the notify icon

---

**UPDATE**
As you can't receive custom messages, you might try this:

1. [enumerate all windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx)
2. iterate over each window and retrieve the processID
3. if the processID matches the one you want to shutdown, send WM_CLOSE to it

retrieving process ID for hWnd:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can't enumerate all windows in Windows Seven if your process is not running under high privileges... Can you confirm this? I could be wrong...

Comment: @Marco I honestly have not tested it. You might be right and this might not work, as the OP stated that he is running as a Windows Service. Aren't Windows Services lacking the right to interact with user windows?

Comment: From Windows Vista on, services cannot create UI objects... this is what I know

Comment: @yas4891: i bind to process by name and iterate over process threads to send WM_QUIT to each thread. i use PostThreadMessage WinAPI for sending messages. but this approach only works if PostThreadMessage is executed in a session of user UI app belongs to. so the complete solution is: use OpenProcessToken to get access token from UI process, then call DuplicateTokenEx to make the token primary and then use CreateProcessAsUser to execute some EXE which actually calls PostThreadMessage. This works in Windows 2003... but not in Windows 7 :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe silly, and I'm not sure this can work within multiple sessions.
Define a custom message and send it to broadcast using `PostMessage`; within your app capture incoming messages and if you receive your custom one, close gracefully.

**In service:**

```
public const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern bool PostMessage(int hwnd, int msg, int wparam, int lparam);
int WM_MYMSG = WM_USER + 1;
```

When you need to send message:

```
PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST,WM_MYMSG,0,0);
```

In your app:

```
int WM_MYMSG = WM_USER + 1;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_MYMSG) Close();
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

**EDITED:**

If you want to override `WndProc` you need to have a form, but that doesn't mean you have to show a form: in your app create a form and run it, while in form code you write:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Show here tray icon
    ....
    ....

    // Hide form
    this.Hide();
}
int WM_MYMSG = WM_USER + 1;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_MYMSG) Close();
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, unfortunatelly the UI app can't handle custom window messages (question is updated).

Comment: @ivan: Why can't your app receive custom messages? I'm curious :)

Comment: thanks for the idea, but I really do not want to introduce main form just to handle custom messages, the architecture of UI app is intentional and works fine. Besides, the UI app can handle standard WM_CLOSE/WM_QUIT messages and I almost got it working... you may find details in comments for yas4891's answer.

Comment: @ivan: I understand that putting an hidden form could be a problem, but it's an easy solution, because you can send to broadcast your custom message without worrying about finding your app among running ones... and you're facing Windows 7 problems with that.
I know my solution is not sugar, but sure it is a faster solution to implement. 
Anyway, keep going for the best way and let us know if you solve your problem as you desire. Good luck :)